# Is this function Lebesgue integrable or integrable in general?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, parametric, riemann-integration

Let $\phi:(0, +\infty) \times [0, +\infty) \to R$ be defined by:

$$
\phi(x, t) =
  \begin{cases}
    e^{-xt}\frac{\sin{t}}{t}       & \quad \text{if } t \neq 0\\
    1  & \quad \text{if } t = 0 \\
  \end{cases}
$$

How can i show that $\forall \space x \in (0, +\infty), \phi \text{ is Lebesgue integrable w.r.t } t \text{ on } [0, +\infty)$

Comment: Hint: The term $\sin(t)/t$ is bounded. And $\exp(-t)$ integrates to 1 on $[0,\intfy)$.

Comment: What is the bound of $\sin{t}\t$

Comment: it is continuous and converges to $0$ for $t\to \infty$. It doesn't really matters... if you need to know, differentiate it...